# Excel =IF(value >= value) not returning right answer

Tags: excel-formula

I have a simple time sheet set up in excel that takes your total hours and removes the 30min break/s if you have any, giving your total hours worked. For some reason it always fails in the case of "0" hours scheduled, for some reason it always returns a "-0.5" instead of a "0" like expected.

```
=IF(E5>=6,E5-0.5,E5)
```

this should simply copy the value from E5 and return the same value if it's not greater than, or equal to, 6.

Comment: what exactly is in cell E5? Is it a formula? If so, what is the formula, what are the precedents cells of the formula? Give us the whole picture. Edit your question to do that. Don't post clarification in a comment. Post a comment if you have added the detail, so the followers of this question get alerted.

Comment: What teylyn said. Also, what exactly is your question to us?

Comment: Works fine for me. Is E5 a formula or just a value? I just created a new blank sheet, put 0, 5, 10, 15 into A1-A4, and put `=IF(A1 >= 6, A1-0.5, A1)` in B1 and then copied down to B4, and every value is exactly what you'd expect.

Comment: Reproducible if the `0` is stored as text and not as a number. What does `=IF(--E5>=6,E5-0.5,--E5)` return?

Comment: Could the E5 cell in question be formatted as some sort of date-time and possibly just off of 0:00 (12:00:00 AM) to cause this?Versions of excel I've used havent run into this, but they've all had some sort of quirks.  What do you get when copying and pasting E5 by value into a cell formatted for a number?